# Quarkus Scheduled Records Processing mechanism Best Practice

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quarkus, quarkus-panache

What is the best practice or way to process the records from DB in scheduled.

Situation:

1. A Microservice based on Quarkus - responsible for sending a communication to customers.
2. DB Table Having Customers Records (100000 customers)
3. Microservice is running on multiple nodes (4 nodes)

Expectation:

1. There should be a scheduler that runs every 5 sec
2. Fetches the records from DB where employee status = pending
3. Should be Multithreaded architecture.
4. Send email to employee email.

**Problem 1:**
The same scheduler running on multiple nodes picks the same records and process How can we avoid this?

**Problem 2:**
Scheduler pics (100 records and processing it) and takes more than 5 seconds and scheduler run again pics few same records. How can we avoid that:

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to run your microservices on kubernetes I would sugest to use an external components as a scheduler and let this component distribute the work over your microservices using messages or HTTP invocations.

As responses to your questions here we go:

1. You can use some locking strategy or "reserve" each row including a field that indicates that your record is being processed and excluding all records containing this fields from your query. By this means when the scheduler fires it will read a set of rows not reserved and use a multithreading approach to process the records, by using a locking strategy (pesimits or optimist) you can prevent other records from marking the same row as reserved for them to be processed. After that the thread thas was able to commit the reserve process the records and updates the state or releases the "reserve" so other workers can work on the record if its needed.
2. You can always instruct your scheduler to do no execute if there is still an execution going.
   `@Scheduled(identity = "ProcessUpdateScheduler", every = "2s", concurrentExecution = Scheduled.ConcurrentExecution.SKIP)`

---

You mainly have two approaches among other possible ones:

1. Pulling (Distribute mining or work distribution): Each instance of the microservice pick a random pending row and mark this row as "processing" commiting the transaction, if its able to commit then this instance holds the right to process this record continuing with its execution, if not it tries to retrieve a different row or just exists waiting for the next invocation. This approach scales horizontally because adding more workers will mean increasing your processing throughput.
2. Pushing (central distribution, distributed processing). You have two kinds of components: First the "Distributor" which is executed with the scheduler and is responsible for picking rows to be processed and marking then as "pending processing", this rows will be forward via a messaging system or HTTP call to the "Processor". The Processor component recieves as input a record and is responsible of processing this record completely or releasing the hold ("procesing pending") state.

Choouse the best suited for your scenario, if you go for the second option, you can have one or more distributors if its necessary, but in order to increment your processing throughput you only need to scale the "Processor" workers